# PIP: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Python/Reference Documentation 3.2'

Tags: python, pypi

I've been trying to upload my package to PyPI by following these steps:

1. Registering on PyPI
2. Creating a hidden `.pypirc` file in my home directory (`~/`) containing:

   ```
   [distutils]
   index-servers = pypi

   [pypi]
   repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
   username=my_username
   password=my_password
   ```
3. Creating `LICENSE.TXT`, `requirements.txt`, and `setup.cfg` inside my package which contained this:

   ```
   [metadata]

   description-file = README.md
   ```
4. Creating `setup.py` in the same directory as my package was (Desktop) which contained this:

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   setup(
     name='Package_name',
     packages=['Package_name'],
     version='1.0',
     description='Description,
     author= 'ShellRox',
     author_email='Email',
     url='Github url',
     download_url='Github download url',
     keywords=['authentication', 'steam', 'simple'],
     classifiers=[],
   )
   ```
5. And finally, executing this command:

   ```
   python setup.py register -r pypitest
   python setup.py sdist bdist_wininst upload
   ```

Which prints this error for some reason:

> error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Python/Reference
>   Documentation 3.2

What could be the problem? Could there be something wrong with my `setup.py`?

Comment: 1. PyPI has stopped accepting uploads of `bdist_wininst` files; only sdists, wheels, and eggs are allowed now.  2. Don't use `distutils`; use `setuptools`, and read https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/

Comment: @jwodder Thanks for the response. So in order to upload package right now, I only need to substitute `from distutils.core import setup` with `from setuptools import setup` and execute `twine upload dist/*` ?